# Is it possible to change pattern recognition of xgettext?

Tags: python, kivy, xgettext

I'm using python, `gettext` and `kivy` to make a multi-language app.

1. I have a label with some text `Label(text = _("hi"))`. I made the code to be able to switch language, but that requires to reset the text, `Label.text = _(Label.text)`, but this code is a problem, since once the translation is done, the text to be used as `msgid` is translated, and therefore, not found in `.po` files the next time.
2. I created a workaround, something like `MyLabel(textKey = msgid)`. This solves all the problems, since changing language is done with `MyLabel.text = _(MyLabel.textKey)`.
3. But this approach has an issue, if I use `xgettext` to generate the `.pot` file, `msgid` is not recognized because it is not written as `_(msgid)` and it cannot be (point 1).

My question is: is there a way to tell `xgettext` to recognise `textKey = msgid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `pygettext`, there I can use the `-k` argument. See [docs](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/pygettext.1.html).